# NSEvent modifier flags not updating until mouse moves

Tags: cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard, nsevent

In Mac OS X 10.6, `NSEvent` has a `+modifierFlags` class method to determind the currently pressed modifier flags. In 10.5, using `[[NSApp currentEvent] modifierFlags]` only updates after mouse move. Is there any way to asynchronously get the modifier flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a comment on [this blog post](http://lipidity.com/apple/modifier-flags-launch/), you can use CGEventCreate() and CGEventGetFlags().

```
CGEventRef event = CGEventCreate(NULL /*default event source*/);
CGEventFlags mods = CGEventGetFlags(event);
if (mods & kCGEventFlagMaskShift)
    NSLog(@"Shift key is being pressed");
```

The modifier flags returned by CGEventGetFlags() (CGEventFlags) are the same as the NSEvent ones.

Answer (score 2):

`GetCurrentKeyModifiers()`. It's a C function but it's available in Cocoa applications (it's part of the Carbon framework, but is still available on 64-bit systems, IIRC.) Note that the flags it uses are not equal to the Cocoa flags, so your tests will have to change appropriately.

Comment: Is it only available on 64-bit systems? I'm trying to target 32-bit systems running 10.5.

Comment: Alexsander Akers: No. It has been available ever since the days of CarbonLib on Mac OS, including on all the 32-bit systems between then and now; he mentioned 64-bit compatibility because a lot of people, upon seeing a Carbon function suggested, will pounce and scream “Carbon's not available in 64-bit!”.